# Grails Unit Testing: Json-Codec missing / How to mock Json-Codec?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, codec

I'm unit testing a controller and currently I'm stuck with the method-call of "encodeAsJSON()" in a service (called by the controller).

I get the MissingMethodException, which I would expect as encodeAsJSON() is a Grails-Codec.

After a bit of searching the `loadCodec`-Method should do what I want.

But I can't import it, because my IDE (SpringSource-ToolSuite) can't find it.

Error:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.codecs.JSONCodec
```

Everything works:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.codecs.HTMLCodec
```

But I don't need the HTMLCodec and the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Plug-ins/codecs.html) doesn't list the JSONCodec.

The method itself is still working (running the application), but I don't know how to unit test it. 
Any ideas? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, further searching and trying got me the answer:

```
Map.metaClass.encodeAsJSON = { -> delegate }
```

The example I used was

```
String.metaClass.encodeAsSha1 = { -> delegate }
```

([Source](http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2008/03/12/mockfor-march-unit-testing-grails-controllers.html))

String didn't work - of course as I'm using a Map, which should be converted to JSON.

I think you have to "mock" (is this real mocking?) it on the Groovy-Interface of the corresponding datatype.

Hope this helps somebody else